# default text in wpf label

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want the below label to be initially populated with default text "Please do not quit the application". 
And when the background task is completed, the label text should change to "Please click on Next to continue."

I used databinding as shown below. The initial string is "Please do not quit the application".
Once the background task is completed, the xml file is updated and hence the label text also updates.

```
<Label Name="label6_3" Content="{Binding XPath=/Cred/DB/Page6/label6_3}"   Foreground="#FF004200" />

initial:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cred>
<DB>
 <Page6>
    <label6_3>Please do not quit the application.</label6_3>
 </Page6>
```

```
 final:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Cred>
      <DB>
        <Page6>
          <label6_3>Please click on Next to continue.</label6_3>
        </Page6>
     </DB>
    </Cred>
```

But the problem in this is , I need to revert back the changes in the xml file before I start the application everytime, 
otherwise the initial string becomes ""Please click on Next to continue." instead of "Please do not quit the application."

How can I avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you should be using XML bindings for something like a temporary label in the GUI.

Comment: Why are you using XML for viewing Data? Maybe you should try out a Trigger that will change the content of the label according to an event or databinding.

Comment: can you give me an example of how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `DataTrigger`. I use `TextBlock` instead of labels but the same applies to `Label` like the one you are using:

```
<TextBlock> 
      <TextBlock.Style>
         <Style>
           <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TaskCompleted}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Task Completed!"/>
             </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```